# Difference between changed compatibility level database and new database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

What is the difference between SQL Server databases A & B where:

A. Database restored from lower level compatibility(100) to higher compatibility (130)

B. New Database created in higher compatibility (130)

Comment: No difference as ultimately both the databases are on compatibility level 130, how they reached there should not be a matter of concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this gets to the root of your question - if not, please update your question with more information.

According the the documentation for [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017), the compatibility mode of a database:

> Sets certain database behaviors to be compatible with the specified
>   version of SQL Server.

As I understand the documentation, two databases running under the same compatibility mode should operate the same way with regard to those specific behaviors.

Restored databases do not (necessarily) *automatically* change their compatibility mode.

From the documentation:

> When a database is upgraded from any earlier version of SQL Server,
>   the database retains its existing compatibility level, if it is at
>   least minimum allowed for that instance of SQL Server. Upgrading a
>   database with a compatibility level lower than the allowed level,
>   automatically sets the database to the lowest compatibility level
>   allowed. This applies to both system and user databases.